How to reconfigure Kestrel after start application
I have method for Kestrel configuration before starting asp.net core minimal API like this:
var clientCertificateThumbprint = "XYZ";
var clientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
var listeningPort = 11101;
var tlsProtocol = SslProtocols.Tls12;
var cert = CertificationService.GetCert();

_builder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.ListenAnyIP(listeningPort, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps(cert, (httpsOptions) =>
        {
            httpsOptions.SslProtocols = tlsProtocol;
            httpsOptions.ClientCertificateMode = clientCertificateMode;
            httpsOptions.ClientCertificateValidation = (certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => ValidateClientCertificate(certificate, clientCertificateThumbprint);
        });
    });
});


private bool ValidateClientCertificate(X509Certificate2? certificate, string thumbprint)
{
    return certificate is null || DateTime.Now > certificate.NotAfter ? false : certificate.Thumbprint.Equals(thumbprint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}

But if I call the same method after application started, it fails with:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The service collection cannot be modified because it is read-only.'
Is there any way how to achieve this?
I cannot use autoreaload from appsettings file, because all this configuration parameters comes from database. But if Kestrel can apply changes from appsettings file, there sholud be exist a way how to do it manually at runtime.
